# Why my views materialized views don't reflect those changes?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, materialized-views, cassandra-3.0

Hi actually I work with cassandra on a project, but I have a problem with materialized views in a moment explain my settings in cassandra and the problem.

I have two instance in Google Cloud, each instance has a node with the next requirements:

- Cassandra version 3.10.0
- CQLSH version 5.0.1

On server

- 1 core-CPU Haswell
- 6.5GB RAM
- HDD 240GB
- Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS

Whenever I update a table that has materilized views, the former gets updated correctly but the materialized views don't reflect those changes.

An example of table that behaves like this has 23 fields:

- 4 fields for partition and clustering keys
- 12 fields for data
- 7 fields for flags that are used as conditions for the materialized view definition
- 8 secondary indexes apply a many fields

The materialized view only copies 12 fields from the original table and the flags are not included on these.

**MODIFIED**

Example of a materialized view sentence:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS sav.laboratorio_unidad AS
    SELECT unidad_politecnica, seccion_politecnica, modulo, datos_modificados, /* Primary Key */
        tipo, id_contacto, contacto, foto, descripcion,
        area, palabra_clave, sector_impacto /* Clasificación */
    FROM sav.laboratorio
    WHERE tipo IS NOT NULL
        AND unidad_politecnica IS NOT NULL 
        AND seccion_politecnica IS NOT NULL
        AND modulo IS NOT NULL
        AND datos_modificados IS NOT NULL
        AND creada_sin_mostrar = false
        AND datos_modificados = false 
        AND validado = true
        AND modificado IS NOT NULL
        AND revisado IS NOT NULL
        AND eliminacion = false
        AND revalidado IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY ((unidad_politecnica), seccion_politecnica, tipo, modulo, datos_modificados);
```

Is the *DESCRIBE* of my table

```
CREATE TABLE sav.laboratorio (
    unidad_politecnica text,
    seccion_politecnica text,
    modulo text,
    datos_modificados boolean,
    actualizado timestamp,
    area set<text>,
    certificado set<frozen<prueba>>,
    contacto frozen<contacto>,
    creada_sin_mostrar boolean,
    creado timestamp,
    descripcion text,
    eliminacion boolean,
    equipamiento frozen<equipo>,
    foto frozen<archivo>,
    id_contacto uuid,
    modificado boolean,
    palabra_clave set<text>,
    revalidado boolean,
    revisado boolean,
    sector_impacto set<text>,
    solicitud_eliminacion boolean,
    tipo text,
    validado boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY (unidad_politecnica, seccion_politecnica, modulo, datos_modificados)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (seccion_politecnica ASC, modulo ASC, datos_modificados ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX laboratorio_creado_sin_mostrar_index ON sav.laboratorio (creada_sin_mostrar);
CREATE INDEX laboratorio_solicitud_eliminacion_index ON sav.laboratorio (solicitud_eliminacion);
CREATE INDEX laboratorio_id_contacto_index ON sav.laboratorio (id_contacto);
CREATE INDEX laboratorio_revisado_index ON sav.laboratorio (revisado);
CREATE INDEX laboratorio_validado_index ON sav.laboratorio (validado);
CREATE INDEX laboratorio_actualizado_index ON sav.laboratorio (actualizado);
CREATE INDEX laboratorio_modificado_index ON sav.laboratorio (modificado);
CREATE INDEX laboratorio_revalidado_index ON sav.laboratorio (revalidado);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sav.laboratorio_unidad AS
    SELECT unidad_politecnica, seccion_politecnica, tipo, modulo, datos_modificados, area, contacto, descripcion, foto, id_contacto, palabra_clave, sector_impacto
    FROM sav.laboratorio
    WHERE tipo IS NOT NULL AND unidad_politecnica IS NOT NULL AND seccion_politecnica IS NOT NULL AND modulo IS NOT NULL AND datos_modificados IS NOT NULL AND creada_sin_mostrar = false AND datos_modificados = false AND validado = true AND modificado IS NOT NULL AND revisado IS NOT NULL AND eliminacion = false AND revalidado IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (unidad_politecnica, seccion_politecnica, tipo, modulo, datos_modificados)
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (seccion_politecnica ASC, tipo ASC, modulo ASC, datos_modificados ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Sorry but my table was written in spanish

**UPDATED**

When an INSERT statement is executed with values that satisfies the given the conditions, the table and the materialized view reflects the changes properly.

The problem is when an INSERT statement with unvalid values is executed, and then an UPDATE statement is executed in order to make the values satisfy the given conditions of the materilized view; in this case the changes are reflected in the table but aren't reflected on the materialized view.

This workflow is neccesary given the requirements of the project.

In this case, when executing and INSERT statement, is not necesary to show the values in the materialized view until the UPDATE statement with the proper values is executed, this is a validation of the data with some boolean flags and we want to make use of the materialized view in order to hide or show the data.

Something to make notice is that we are using a single keyspace with 40 tables and 19 materialized views, 10 materialized views are having the same problem.

Comment: Show your base table schema

Answer (score 0):

**Before Cassandra 3.10**

> The columns that are not part of the base table primary key can only be restricted by an IS NOT NULL restriction. No other restriction is allowed.

**In Cassandra 3.10 the issue is solved with CASSANDRA-10368**

- Support filtering on non-PRIMARY KEY columns in the CREATE
  MATERIALIZED VIEW statement's WHERE clause (CASSANDRA-10368)

Source : https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/CHANGES.txt#L361

**Edited#1**

I think you are missing some field when insertion or your inserted data doesn't satisfy the where clause.In your case Data will be copied to Materialized View If and only if data satisfy the below condition that you define in the where clause

```
 tipo IS NOT NULL 
 AND unidad_politecnica IS NOT NULL 
 AND seccion_politecnica IS NOT NULL 
 AND modulo IS NOT NULL 
 AND datos_modificados IS NOT NULL 
 AND creada_sin_mostrar = false 
 AND datos_modificados = false 
 AND validado = true 
 AND modificado IS NOT NULL 
 AND revisado IS NOT NULL 
 AND eliminacion = false 
 AND revalidado IS NOT NULL
```

Here is an example insert statement that satisfy the above condition :

```
INSERT INTO laboratorio (
    tipo, 
    unidad_politecnica,
    seccion_politecnica, 
    modulo, 
    datos_modificados, 
    modificado, 
    revisado, 
    revalidado, 
    creada_sin_mostrar, 
    eliminacion, 
    validado
) VALUES ( 
    'tipo', 
    'unidad', 
    'seccion', 
    'modulo', 
    false, 
    true, 
    true, 
    true, 
    false, 
    false, 
    true
);
```

Output :

```
cqlsh:sav> SELECT * FROM laboratorio_unidad ;

@ Row 1
---------------------+---------
 unidad_politecnica  | unidad
 seccion_politecnica | seccion
 tipo                | tipo
 modulo              | modulo
 datos_modificados   | False
 area                | null
 descripcion         | null
 id_contacto         | null
 palabra_clave       | null
 sector_impacto      | null
```

**Edited#2**

**Found the Problem**,  the problem is in your Materialized View Definition, In the where clause you have define relation with some column (`creada_sin_mostrar, validado, modificado, revisado, eliminacion, revalidado`) which in not present in the selection clause. Add the missing column in the selection clause.

So your Materialized View Schema should be :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS sav.laboratorio_unidad AS
    SELECT unidad_politecnica, seccion_politecnica, modulo, datos_modificados,
        tipo, id_contacto, contacto, foto, descripcion,
        area, palabra_clave, sector_impacto,
        creada_sin_mostrar, validado, modificado, revisado, eliminacion, revalidado
    FROM sav.laboratorio
    WHERE tipo IS NOT NULL
        AND unidad_politecnica IS NOT NULL 
        AND seccion_politecnica IS NOT NULL
        AND modulo IS NOT NULL
        AND datos_modificados IS NOT NULL
        AND creada_sin_mostrar = false
        AND datos_modificados = false 
        AND validado = true
        AND modificado IS NOT NULL
        AND revisado IS NOT NULL
        AND eliminacion = false
        AND revalidado IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY ((unidad_politecnica), seccion_politecnica, tipo, modulo, datos_modificados);
```

**You have to add the missing column otherwise it will not reflect your change correctly. This is an open issue in cassandra**

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13547
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11500

Comment: I'm using Cassandra 3.10 and the problem remains, the materialized view doesn't update as soon as I update the table. Is there any special way to update the table in order to get the materialized view updated?

Comment: @carson314 Found the solution check the updated answer